# How can I debug between activities?

Tags: android, debugging, android-activity

I am calling other activity with intent in main class

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, List.class);
intent.putExtra("email", email);
intent.putExtra("password", password);
**startActivity(intent);**
```

I am starting to debug on the line Intent line but I couldnt pass the other activity

The other is ;

```
public class List extends Activity 
{ 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        **setContentView(R.layout.emaillist);**

        **final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();**
        String email = extras.getString(MainActivity.email);
        String password = extras.getString(MainActivity.password);  
        listofmails(email , password );
    }


 public void epostaListeleme(String eposta, String sifre) 
    {
           ....
    }
```

How can I pass from MainActivity to ListActivity on debug?

Answer (score 2):

its better to make *breakpoint* on other activity. why you want to debug intent action i didnt understand?

Comment: I did but it didnt work. Debug happen only in mainactivity. I want to pass ListActivity

Comment: where you made breakpoint on other activity?, i mean exact line.

Comment: The lines are with stars in the question

Comment: no, just remove break point from there and put the breakpoint on `onCreate()` on activity to be called.

Comment: Thank you, it is on debug now. But I have another problem, in the main activity I add email and password into the intent and on debug they filled true email and password items. But in the List activity on these lines String email = extras.getString(MainActivity.email);
        String password = extras.getString(MainActivity.password);  Email and password are null. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: I am assuming debug only working on ListActivity now and the email and password are not filling.

Comment: try this `String email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("email");
String password = getIntent().getExtras().getString("password");`